# Changing the ID of html elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which allows user to add elements(which might be a field set or a text box) dynamically. I'm able to assign a new ID to the elements when added but I'm not able to make it in a sequence as the user can add elements in between as well.

So for example, there is an Id named XXX1 and the user adds a new element after it which is xxx2. Now if the user adds a new element again after XXX1, it comes up as XXX3. So the order of the elements is XXX1, XXX3, XXX2. I'm not able to control the names when it is being added. So I'm trying to re-assign the names after add.

I'm trying to get all elements in an array and change the ID as follows

```
document.getElementById('xxx3').setAttribute('id', 'xxx2');
```

But this doesn't work as ID XXX2 already exists for another element. Please help me with a solution for this.

Comment: If you're only changing the ID for the sake of order, I'd leave it - it's something that rarely *needs* to happen.

Comment: I can't see exactly why you need to do it - I'd just leave it as it is. Otherwise it sound like a normal "swapping two variables" type situation.

Comment: bu the way, the id will get reset, only problem being you'll have 2 elements with the id as xxx2

Comment: Why are you allowing the user to "id" the element? expand a little bit on your problem, maybe there is another workaround

Answer (score 0):

So why not change the ID of `xxx2` first, to move it out of the way, then putting it back in place later?

```
document.getElementById('xxx2').setAttribute('id', 'temporaryId');
document.getElementById('xxx3').setAttribute('id', 'xxx2');
document.getElementById('temporaryId').setAttribute('id', 'xxx3');
```

Comment: If you're going to use a temporary dummy ID, then you don't have to change `xxx2` first.

Comment: How so? I'm doing it because having to elements with the same ID value is illegal in HTML.

Comment: I mean, you can just as easily set `xxx3` to the temporary ID then move `xxx2` to `xxx3` and change the temp to `xxx2`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go from the last element to the first(the one's after the position you are inserting to) and add one to the ID?

for example:

```
var insertAt = 2; // for an element to be called xxx2
var els = [...]; // an array with all of the elements
if(els.length >= insertAt){
  for(var i = els.length-1; i >= insertAt-1; --i){
    els[i].setAttribute('id', 'xxx'+(i+2));
  }
}
// Add the new element here which will be called xxx2
```